# How to increase the ActionDown Time in OnTouchEvent In Android?

Tags: android, android-listview

In my application,When Touch on List view I need to open a image and When Action_UP called i need to release the image.Here my problem is ,i need to press item 5 second after that i will open image,but when i using onTouch event just i touch on list view the image will open.I need to increase the time of touch event please can any one help me?

Thanking in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Put a Handler in your onItemClickListener of your ListView inside of your adapter class (in getView function) :

```
row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        }
    }, 5000);

}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setOnItemLongClickListener()` of a listview. with an example given below:

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int pos, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Log.v("long clicked","pos"+" "+pos);

                return true;
            }
        });
```

I think this will help...

Answer (score 0):

You can use[GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html). Just declare a new GestureDetector and in onTouchEvent method just make a switch clause by EventType. If it is ACTION_DOWN open an image, if it is ACTION_UP release it

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE : Do not setOnItemClickListener() on listview.**

*You can achieve this by doing some trick in your list adapter.*

*Go to your list adapter and in getView() method.*

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


       convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        //your code

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
        //do your code to open image.
        return true;
    }
    });
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: how i can release my image.